# gtkmm: How to detect arrow key is pressed

Tags: c++, keypress, gtkmm

What event can i connect to in order to detect arrow keys being pressed when a user is in a window.

So far i have tried to connect via `on_key_press_event` and i checked `keyval`, `hardware_keycode`, and `state`.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MyWindow();
    bool onKeyPress(GdkEventKey*);
};

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    set_title("arrow_button_test");
    this->signal_key_press_event().connect( sigc::mem_fun( *this, &MyWindow::onKeyPress ) );
}

bool MyWindow::onKeyPress(GdkEventKey* event)
{
    std::cout << event->keyval << ' ' << event->hardware_keycode << ' ' << event->state << std::endl;

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.almost-university.gtkmm.arrow_button_press");

    MyWindow window;    

    app->run(window);

    return 0;
}
```

This code generates no output on arrow keys, meaning that event isn't even fired off.

Comment: What is the point for the downvote? At lease comment and say what i should have done to imporve the question. I did search and no such question was asked before, and it is *not* clear from reading documentation. I have also provided the code and my reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change

```
this->signal_key_press_event().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyWindow::onKeyPress));
```

to

```
this->signal_key_press_event().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyWindow::onKeyPress), false);
```

your signal handler should receive the events. That `false` argument is for the `after` flag. It is `true` by default, meaning that other signal handlers may intercept the signal before `MyWindow::onKeyPress`, since it is the last one.